# spring and rest

Tags: spring, rest

I created the code below but I seem to get the following error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/restspring/service/employees/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'restspring'" when I access the service using "http://localhost:8080/restspring/service/employees/1". Did I miss something?

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   /web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restspring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restspring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### restspring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="classesToBeBound">
<list>
    <value>spring3.rest.bean.Employees</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="employees" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
<constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
<property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
        <bean     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
        <bean id="viewResolver"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"         value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

### employees.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
<thead><tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
</tr></thead>
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees.employees}">
<tr>
    <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
    <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

### EmployeesController.java

```
package spring3.rest.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import spring3.rest.bean.Employees;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeesController {
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/{id}")
  public ModelAndView getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") String id){
      Employees e = new Employees();
      e.setFirstName("Eugene");
      e.setLastName("Anthony");
      return new ModelAndView("employees", "employees", e);
  }
}
```

### Employees.java

```
package spring3.rest.bean;

public class Employees {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

Your help is kindly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Which is the version of spring used? Is there any error messages in the server after the request is failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some steps as given in [this document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-setup).

You need to define two beans

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

and then add a component scan for the controller path
ex

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the resulting war file? By default, that constitutes your *context root* and should be added to your request before the `/service/employees/1` in your request url. The `<servlet-name>` of your `web.xml` is just a logical name for mapping a request (identified by the `<url-pattern>`) to a specific servlet, it is not a part of the url. Try omitting it when you make a request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a component scan to detect your controller . If you have missed it , put it in . Sample

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.myProject.controller"/>
```

This detects the @Controller annotation and also auto enables the <context:annotation-config> to process the annotations.

Check the link at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller for more info .